# How rails server understand whether a request is xml or json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, json

In rails app how server understand whether a request is xml or json? http header for both request is same.

Answer (score 0):

[**Mime Types**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type)

Every request you send through HTTP has a mime type, which means that Rails can pick this up with its [ActionDispatch::Request](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html) handler

The way you respond to the different mime-types is to use [`respond_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to):

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def new
    respond_to do |format| 
        format.html
        format.js
    end
end
```